# I would like a hint in order to prove that this matrix is positive definite

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $a_{ij}$ be a real number for all $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$. Consider the matrix below.

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{1k})^2 & \sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}a_{2k} & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}a_{nk}\\ 
\sum_{k=1}^na_{2k}a_{1k} & \sum_{k=1}^n(a_{2k})^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^na_{2k}a_{nk}\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}a_{1k} & \sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}a_{2k} & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^n(a_{nk})^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to prove that $B$ is definite positive. Notice that $B$ is symmetric, because
$$b_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}a_{jk}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{jk}a_{ik}=b_{ji}$$

I think that symmetry is helpful in this case. Maybe I'll need a theorem (that I don't know!) about sufficient conditions for positive definiteness. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this not just the product of some matrix with its transpose?

Comment: Yeah, $B = AA^T$ for $A = (a_{ij})$, now just try to show $x^T A A^T x > 0$ for any nonzero $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by the commenters, this is the product of a matrix with its transpose. Such a product is always positive semidefinite. It is positive definite if and only if $A$ is invertible. (Correction here due to @julien).

Suppose $B=AA^T$. We must show $x^TAA^Tx>0$ for all nonzero $x$. This is $x^TA(x^TA)^T$, or the inner product of $x^TA$ with itself. Since $v\cdot v=\|v\|^2$ for any vector $v$, and the norm is positive definite, we are done.

Comment: More precisely: semidefinite positive. And definite positive iff $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @julien You are right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: What happens if the matrix has order $m\neq n$, like below?$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{1k})^2 & \sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}a_{2k} & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}a_{mk}\\ 
\sum_{k=1}^na_{2k}a_{1k} & \sum_{k=1}^n(a_{2k})^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^na_{2k}a_{mk}\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
\sum_{k=1}^na_{mk}a_{1k} & \sum_{k=1}^na_{mk}a_{2k} & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^n(a_{mk})^2
\end{bmatrix}$$ Actually, I need this case.

Comment: @PerguntadorDeperguntas I am not sure what you mean by order. You should ask that as a new question.