# Could someone help me to prove that this symmetric matrix is definite positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Let $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}$ for all $i,j\in\{1,...,n\}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the matrix below.

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{1k})^2 & \sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}a_{2k} & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^na_{1k}a_{mk}\\ 
\sum_{k=1}^na_{2k}a_{1k} & \sum_{k=1}^n(a_{2k})^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^na_{2k}a_{mk}\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
\sum_{k=1}^na_{mk}a_{1k} & \sum_{k=1}^na_{mk}a_{2k} & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^n(a_{mk})^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to prove that $B$ is definite positive. Notice that $B$ is symmetric (I think that symmetry is helpful in this case). If $n=m$, there is a answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421526/i-would-like-a-hint-in-order-to-prove-that-this-matrix-is-positive-definite). But I need the general case.

I hope you help me.

Thanks.

Comment: OK, $B$ is square.

Comment: For $A = \left[ a_{ij}\right]_{m\times n}$, we have $B=AA^\mathrm{T}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think it meant to be positive semidefinite in the question.

Comment: It is not a huge stretch from the square case to the rectangular one.

Comment: How does this question differ from your last question? It appears that they are the same.

Comment: You cite a question that proves this if $B$ is square, then in your first comment you say OK, $B$ is square.  Why aren't we done? It should be positive semidefinite, because all the $a_{ij}$ could be zero, so $B$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: @RossMillikan In the previous question $B=AA^T$ with $A$ square. Now $A$ is rectangular. Not a big difference, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B=AA^\top$ is positive definite if and only if the row vectors of $A$ are linearly independent, i.e., $\text{rank}\,(A)=m$. Same holds when $A$ is square. $B$ is always positive semidefinite because $Bv\cdot v=\|A^\top v\|^2\ge 0$.