# How to show that the Hessian matrix of $G$ is positive definite?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\{g_i:X\subset\Bbb R\to\Bbb R;\;i=1,\ldots,m\}$ be a linearly independent set of real functions.

Given $n$ points $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)\in X,$ consider the following function

$$G(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{l=1}^m\left[ \beta_lg_l(x_k)-y_k\right]\right)^2$$

I need to prove that $G$ attains a local minimum. For this, I need to show that the Hessian matrix of $G$ is positive definite, but I'm not able to do. I'm trying to show it, but I'm able to prove that it's just positive semidefinite (for this, I'm doing things like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421526/i-would-like-a-hint-in-order-to-prove-that-this-matrix-is-positive-definite) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421590/could-someone-help-me-to-prove-that-this-symmetric-matrix-is-definite-positive)). Can someone help me show that the Hessian matrix of $G$ is positive definite?

Notice that

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \beta_i}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(2g_i(x_k)\sum_{l=1}^m\left[ \beta_lg_l(x_k)-y_k\right]\right)$$

and

$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial \beta_j\beta_i}=2\sum_{k=1}^ng_i(x_k)g_j(x_k)$$

Hence, the Hessian matrix of $G$ is

$$H=2
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)^2 & \sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)g_2(x_k) & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_1(x_k)g_m(x_k)\\ 
\sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)g_1(x_k) & \sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)^2 & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_2(x_k)g_m(x_k)\\ 
 &  & \vdots & \\ 
\sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)g_1(x_k) & \sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)g_2(x_k) & \cdots & \sum_{k=1}^ng_m(x_k)^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the matrix $A$ with entries $ A_{kj} = g_j(x_k) $ then $A$ should be invertible from linear independence of $g_i$s and you have entries of Hessian assuming your calculation as 
$$ H_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial \beta_i\partial \beta_j} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^n A^T_{ik} A_{kj} $$
Hence $ H = 2A^T A $ which is always positive definite for invertible $A$.

Comment: A is not necessarily square. And if A is square, some cases it's not invertible (its columns are not linearly independent. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422015/show-that-this-set-is-linearly-independent).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readability, I'm going to rename some of your variables.

Suppose the given set of linearly independent functions is $\{\varphi_i:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\mid i=1,\ldots,m\}$  and the given ponts are $(x_1,f_1),\ldots,(x_n,f_n).$

Now, if we change $G$ into $S$  and $(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m)$ into $(a_1,\ldots,a_m),$ we can approach your problem as follows:
\begin{aligned}S(a_0,\ldots,a_m):&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(f_k-\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\varphi_i(x_k)\right)^2\\\text{searching for candidates}&\text{ for the minimum}\\0=\frac{\partial S}{\partial a_j}(a_0,\ldots,a_m)&=-2\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi_j(x_k)\left(f_k-\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\varphi_i(x_k)\right)\\\Rightarrow\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi_j(x_k)\varphi_i(x_k)a_i&=\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi_j(x_k)f_k,j=1,\ldots,m\\A:&=\begin{bmatrix}\varphi_1(x_1)&\varphi_2(x_1)&\ldots&\varphi_m(x_1)\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\varphi_1(x_n)&\varphi_2(x_n)&\ldots&\varphi_m(x_n)\end{bmatrix}\\\Rightarrow\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\varphi_1(x_1)&\ldots&\varphi_1(x_n)\\\varphi_2(x_1)&\ldots&\varphi_2(x_n)\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\varphi_m(x_1)&\ldots&\varphi_m(x_n)\end{bmatrix}}_{A^T}\cdot\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\varphi_1(x_1)&\varphi_2(x_1)&\ldots&\varphi_m(x_1)\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\varphi_1(x_n)&\varphi_2(x_n)&\ldots&\varphi_m(x_n)\end{bmatrix}}_{A}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_m\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi_1(x_k)f_k\\\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi_2(x_k)f_k\\\vdots\\\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi_m(x_k)f_k\end{bmatrix}\\\langle B\mathbf a,\mathbf a\rangle&=\langle A^TA\mathbf a,\mathbf a\rangle\\&=\langle A\mathbf a,A\mathbf a\rangle\\&=\|A\mathbf a\|_2^2\\&=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\begin{bmatrix}\varphi_i(x_1)\\\varphi_i(x_2)\\\vdots\\\varphi_i(x_n)\end{bmatrix}\right\|>0\end{aligned} since $\varphi_i$'s are linearly independent, $$\begin{aligned}\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\varphi_i&=0\\\Leftrightarrow\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\varphi_i(x)&=0,\forall x\in\Bbb R\\\Leftrightarrow a_i&=0,\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}.\end{aligned}$$ Your solution $\mathbf a$ must then be unique.